# Is it possible to apply CLEAR_TOP flag for activity in manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I want to have an activity which clears top (clearTop=true) whenever there is an intent to start that activity. Right now I have to control the activity start from every place and manually add (xamarin.android syntax) activity flag to intent:

```
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
```

Please advise how to put this behavior into manifest/attribute

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. You will probably have to use a BroadcastReceiver and fire off an intent with the flags manually.

Comment: or you can create a utility method that adds that flag

Answer (score 0):

Put attribute android:launchMode="singleTop" to your activity

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I put it info manifest. But it is not enough. If activity is not top then new activity will be created instead of clearing all the activities in back stack backwards to desired activity.

Comment: "singleTask" or "singleInstance" are also not appropriate ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know then